# What's the difference between patent and obvious?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Patent is used a lot more in "serious" matters, like legal breaches, such as a "patent breach of law," but does that really mean anything? Does "patent" just sound more refined?

Comment: Yes; they're synonyms, but 'patent' tends to be reserved for special usages (as you say, legal; 'patent leather' ...) or to emphasise by using a more formal register.

Comment: Sometimes we use both of them for emphasis: _patently obvious_.

Answer (score 2):

An *obvious* truth is one which is instantly recognized, but one which may not hold up on careful examination.

A *patent* truth is incontrovertible, but it may not be instantly recognized.

In many cases. of course, something will be *both* obvious and patent. In that case, a political candidate would use *patent* when trying to emphasize the validity of his own opinions, and *obvious* when trying to humiliate and discredit those expressing contrary opinions.